# how to get all the elements from a list using one as a key.?

Tags: java

Suppose i have a list of employees containing their data as
emp name
emp manager
emp lead 
emp project
emp band
......

so how is it possible to have a output like for each project .... sort the name of manager and display.`package com.office.code;

public class Employee {

```
    int empno;  
    String empname;  
    String empmanager;
    String empproject;
    String emplead;
    String empband;
    public Employee(int empno, String empname, String empmanager, String empproject, String emplead,
            String empband) {
        super();
        this.empno = empno;
        this.empname = empname;
        this.empmanager = empmanager;
        this.empproject = empproject;
        this.emplead = emplead;
        this.empband = empband;
    }
```

}
`

as for:--project1

```
            manager1 name1  lead1 band1
            manager2 name2  lead2 band2
            manager3 name3  lead3 band3
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve it?

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what you want.  I'd recommend using JDK8, lambdas, and filters on that List<Employee>.

Comment: I used Comparator for this and i get the sorted list based on project name .... But i want to get it sorted as name of manager for each project..

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand this is what you want:

```
public void sort(ArrayList<Employee> employees){
    ArrayList<String> projects=new ArrayList<>();
        for(Employee employee:employees){
            if(!projects.contains(employee.empproject)) {
                for (Employee employe : employees) {
                    if (employee.empproject.equals(employe.empproject)) {
                        System.out.println(employe.empname);
                        //.
                        //.
                        //.
                        //for all the fields
                    }
                }
                projects.add(employee.empproject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please try it, and tell me if it is ok.